# Why do my objects appear with Object Id and Object ID?

Tags: reporting, standard-objects, id

I'm trying to do a report. However, whenever I want to use something like filter by name, this Name field doesn't exist, it is designated as being "Object Id", which is a lookup to "Object ID" (all uppercase).

Is there anyway to rename this "Object Id" to "Object Name"?

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow the steps mentioned below to change the label of 'Object ID' to 'Object Name'

1. Setup - Create - Report Types
2. New Custom Report Type
3. Complete the fields for Primary Object, Report Type Label, Report Type Name,
   Description, Store in Category, and Deployment Status. Save.
4. Select Edit Layout. Select the field(s) you would like to rename (in this case Object Id) and click Edit Properties.
5. Rename the label(s) and Save. Now use this custom report type to create a report.

Once you follow these, you should see the new labels on your report.